# High and unstable TTFB

Tags: performance

Website concerned : [www.collectifbam.fr](https://www.collectifbam.fr)

As you can see, the TTFB of the website is very unstable, sometimes extremely slow. It even reached more than 30s just for the DOM element. Sometimes it's normal, depending on the minute you run the test. [image]

I made test with various web tools such as https://tools.keycdn.com/performance, or [Geek Flare](https://gf.dev/ttfb-test) and TTFB's are high regardless of the location. However, files are light. The heavier file weighs 97ko (bundle.css). The chrome console throws an error that doesn't seem to be related : `custom.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`
I'm not very experienced with that kind of issues so tell me if you need more informations, code's sample etc.

For me it seems that it comes from the server, but I'm quite a noob regarding that sort of issues. The use of a shared server could explain the unstability. But I wanted to have other opinions before trying to work on that dimension that can implies to subscribe to a more efficient offer, which means higher costs.

Comment: What do you mean by "unstable"? Does it vary a lot or is it persistently high?

Comment: indeed it varies a lot, depending on the minute when you do the test. Sometimes it's normal.